# Getting count of points in grid using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, count, aggregate

I am using Google Earth Engine to map attacks between armed groups in Colombia. I added a grid to the map and I want to get a count of attacks per 'dyad_name' per grid square.

Among the many things I tried, aggregate_count is the nearest I've gotten. But I still can't do what I need.

How can I do this?

This is my code:

[Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Flaurarolda%2FforestchangeCol%3Acountattacks)

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017");
var colombia = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'CO'));

var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/laurarolda/ged191");

// 1. GRID
function makeGrid(colombia, scale) {
  // pixelLonLat returns an image with each pixel labeled with longitude and
  // latitude values.
  var lonLat = ee.Image.pixelLonLat();

  // Select the longitude and latitude bands, multiply by a large number then
  // truncate them to integers.
  var lonGrid = lonLat
    .select('longitude')
    .multiply(10000000)// 7 zeros
    .toInt();

  var latGrid = lonLat
    .select('latitude')
    .multiply(10000000) // 7 zeros
    .toInt();

  // To produce the grid, multiply the latitude and longitude images and then use
  // reduce to vectors at the 10km resolution to group the grid into vectors.
  return lonGrid
    .multiply(latGrid)
    .reduceToVectors({
      geometry: colombia, // This is undefined until you draw a geometry.
      scale: scale,
      geometryType: 'polygon',
    });
}

function buildGeometryList(grid, limit) {
  return grid.toList(limit).map(function(feature) {
    var featureGeometry = ee.Feature(feature).geometry();
    var coordinates = featureGeometry.coordinates().get(0);
    return ee.Geometry.LinearRing(coordinates);
  });
}

var grid = makeGrid(colombia, 100000); // 10 km scale // 4 zeros
var geometries = buildGeometryList(grid, 1000); // 3 zeros

var drawingTools = Map.drawingTools();
geometries.evaluate(function(geometriesList) {
  var layer = ui.Map.GeometryLayer({
    geometries : geometriesList,
    name: 'grid',
    color: 'black',
    shown: true, // Show the layer (already defaults to true).
    locked: true, // Lock the layer.
  });
  drawingTools.layers().set(1, layer);
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// 2. Filter attacks for the year 2018 in Colombia
var ged_col_18 = ged.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country', 'Colombia')).filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', 2018));

// 2.1 Aggregate the number of attacks in 2018
print('Number of attacks during 2018',
      ged_col_18.aggregate_count('dyad_name')) // 57 - number of attacks during 2018
```

Comment: The link/repository you shared doesn't exist: 'Repository "users/laurarolda/forestchangeCol" does not exist'

Comment: it does work for me